# How to convert array with ranges in to alone array in ruby

Tags: ruby, arrays, range

I have some array

```
>> a = ["a..c", "0..2"]
=> ["a..c", "0..2"]
```

I need convert this array to another array

```
>> b = ("a".."c").to_a + (0..2).to_a
=> ["a", "b", "c", 0, 1, 2]
```

How I can do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

what about this?

```
a = ["a..c", "0..2"]

b = a.map { |e| Range.new( *(e).split('..') ).to_a }.flatten
```

no `flat_map` used so it works the same on all versions

as @steenslag correctly mentioned, this version does not convert to integers.

here is a version that does:

```
b = a.map do |e| 
  Range.new( *(e).split('..').map{ |c| c =~ /\A\d+\Z/ ? c.to_i : c } ).to_a 
end.flatten
```

### see it in action [here](http://cibox.org/slivu/stackoverflow?lang=ruby&file=how-to-convert-array-with-ranges-in-to-alone-array-in-ruby.rb&run=true&versions=%2a#)

Comment: Thanx, I have 1.8.7 version of Ruby and this example is worked!

Answer (score 3):

```
a.flat_map do |string_range| 
  from, to = string_range.split("..", 2)
  (from =~ /^\d+$/ ? (from.to_i..to.to_i) : (from..to)).to_a 
end 
#=> => ["a", "b", "c", 0, 1, 2]
```

Answer (score 2):

```
a = ["a..c", "0..2"]
b = a.flat_map{|str| Range.new(*str.split('..')).to_a} # => ["a", "b", "c", "0", "1", "2"]
p b.map!{|v| Integer(v) rescue v} # => ["a", "b", "c", 0, 1, 2]
```